# Why did my gecko die?

Tags: leopard-geckos

So, about a month ago my gecko of three years died i'm still devasted to this day..It was a heart breaking moment...she was not eating at all nor drinking my dad said she was laying her infertile eggs so I relaxed a bit (my dad talked to a vet) and her stomach started to swell a lot she had dead skin stuck to her hands which made her put her arms a weird way when she slept. She also started to not move at all, all she ever did was sleep and it started concerning me. She had lip and eye infections. Her name was Plinxton. We were going to take her to the vet but sadly the night before we were going to...she passed away I know y'all are going to say "how do you know she was dead?" well, for starters she wasn't breathing anymore. She was even limper than what she was. She had no heart beat. Lastly she was pale. She was in so much pain she couldn't lift her lower part of her body. I miss her soo much. Does anyone of you know what my gecko had? please and thank you for reading this..